# Mongo explain result for aggregation pipeline gives different result as compared to normal query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Mongo explain result for aggregation pipeline gives different result as compared to normal query .

```
I have my index on order_settlement_status.
```

query 1 :

```
 db.restaurant_service_orders.find({order_settlement_status :1}).explain()
```

which gives "cursor" : "BtreeCursor order_settlement_status_1",

query 2 :

```
db.collection.runCommand('aggregate', {pipeline: [{$match :{order_settlement_status : 1}}], explain: true})
```

which gives "cursor" : "BasicCursor"

Please explain why a different behaviour for aggregation pipeline.

Comment: How about running it with `db.collection.aggregate(...)` instead of `runCommand`?

Comment: @SalvadorDali : db.restaurant_service_orders.aggregate([{$match :{order_settlement_status : 1}}],{explain:true})  This doesnt explain the query , rather it gives the output.

Comment: strange, because [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#return-information-on-aggregation-pipeline-operation) tells that it should explain it.

Comment: @SalvadorDali :  MongoDb version is  2.4.10, may be that is the reason

Comment: @zooney: definitely try in 2.6+ - explains don't work properly for aggregation before 2.6.  This is not explicitly called out, but if you look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/ you will notice that explain is listed as "New in version 2.6"